# When I press S for scale it wants to shrink/flatten

Tags: modeling, keymap

So when I want to scale (still a noob) it just raises the plane.

In the top right (when I press <kbd>S</kbd>) it says 'Shrink/Fatten', not 'Scale'

Comment: Don't worry, there will be a solution. The normal shortcut for Shrink / Fatten is Alt-S.  If you don't have a stuck Alt-key, to help others figure out what's up, could you check out your KeyMap,, under Header > Edit > Preferences? Have a look at the S and Alt-S bindings, and include those in your question.. https://imgur.com/a/gPVFPHf

Comment: If you go into the Preferences >Keymap, click on Name and press Resize, what do you have under 3D View? Maybe you've changed the shortcut?

Comment: I did check the keybindings and shrink is alt-s.. what now?

Comment: try resetting to factory defaults by clicking file and then reset to factory defaults